# Detecting missing annotations in code

Tags: java, annotations, sonarqube

Is there a way to detect missing annotations in code using Sonarqube. Does it have any inbuilt rules for it.

If there is a way, can we also detect missing annotations on new code?

Comment: To what annotations are you referring exactly? You have rule squid:S1161 which detect missing @Override annotation: ""@Override" annotation should be used on any method overriding (since Java 5) or implementing (since Java 6) another one"
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1161